# Unable to change eclipse line length or comment line length

Tags: eclipse

I've tried changing all of the line wrapping parameters, both increasing and decreasing the maximum line length for source and comments, as well as disabling comment formatting. However, I'm unable to affect the code formatter's line-splitting behavior. No matter what changes I make to the format, line splitting occurs at 120 characters for both comments and source code. I've also tried upgrading eclipse from 3.6 to 3.7.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, I eventually resolved this by deleting .classpath, .project, and the .settings folder; regenerating the project files with maven; and deleting/re-importing the project. I'm not sure which of these caused the effect (I suspect it was deleting .settings) and still do not know why my code formatter changes were not having an effect prior to taking these steps. If anyone knows why this might have happened, I would love to know.

Comment: Perhaps the project had a project-specific code style set, and it was different from the one you were editing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on your project and go to `Properties`
2. Check if `Java Code Style` > `Formatter` > `Enable project specific settings` is checked
3. If so, check the `Active profile`

My guess is that there was a different `Active profile` selected than the one you were editing.  Deleting the project and recreating it caused the project to return to the default code style profile, where `Enable project specific settings` is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the lines width from :

Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter >> then editing the maximum line width ?